# Cayley-Hamilton theorem for symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, cayley-hamilton

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. We know that by Cayley-Hamilton theorem
\begin{aligned}A^{-1}={\frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{\det A}}(A^{n-1}+c_{n-1}A^{n-2}+\cdots +c_{1}I_{n}).\end{aligned}

How can we simplify this expression, by knowing that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite?

Specific questions: Can we say the $c_j$ ($j=1,...,n-1$) are positive?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  Say for $n=3$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}>0$, then $A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{-1}{1}(\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}+(-3)I)$.

$c_1$ is negative here.